# Transfer files from one server to another using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, server, windows-server-2012-r2

I have certain files in a folder on my local machine (<kbd>Windows 8</kbd>) and I want to transfer them to a remote server (<kbd>Windows server 2012 R2</kbd>) using a batch script.

Shown below is the script that I am trying to run but it throws an `Invalid drive specification error`. 
**Note:** I am sure that there is a folder called `test` in the specified location.

#### map.bat

```
xcopy /-y C:\Users\ssubburathinam\Documents\map1\*.* \\192.168.1.11\C:\Users\ssubburathinam\Desktop\test\ /d /c /y  
pause
```

#### Screenshot of error

[image]

I do not know where to put my login credentials in this script as the remote server has login enabled. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: To use the administrative share you use a dollar symbol. `\\192.168.1.11\C$`

Comment: For future reference you can copy and paste from the cmd window.  A lot easier to copy and paste the text from the cmd window then it is to upload  screen shot for everyone to see. Time is money.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the "Add a network location" in the main computer, so you can see a new drive letter with the network location. For your try, it might be wrong the share name on the remote computer, if you share a folder, usually is called by:

```
\\IP_or_name_of_the_remote_server\shared_name
```

Comment: He is trying to use the administrative share.

Comment: I created a shared folder named `File Transfer` and replaced the command `xcopy /-y C:\Users\ssubburathinam\Documents\map1\*.* \\192.168.1.11\File Transfer /d /c /y`. It still throws the same error.

Comment: @SuhasSrivatsSubburathinam, file paths with spaces must have quotes surrounding the entire path.  Regardless of that I showed you how to use the administrative share in my comment above.

Comment: As @Squashman say, if you have spaces in the name of the share, or any folder, use quotes: "\\192.168.1.11\File Transfer"  Check this page, this might be more usefull to you:
http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/map-network-drive-windows-10